# Delphi Bug in Indy FTP List method?

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I'm trying to generate a list of files matching a certain file mask and Indy falls over with this error

> EidReplyRFCError with message '*.*': No such file or directory.

I've tried several variations and this is the result:

`FTP.List( aFiles, '', true );`   => this works

`FTP.List( aFiles, '*.*', false );`  => this works too

`FTP.List( aFiles, '*.*', true );`   => this fails

`FTP.List( aFiles, '*.zip', true );`   => this fails too (despite it being the example in the latest documentation)

`FTP.List( '*.*', false );`  => this works

`FTP.List( '*.*', true );`  => this fails

I'm using Delphi XE5 & Indy version 10.6. The same issue exists in XE8 if relevant.

Maybe the functionality has changed and the documentation is now wrong or it's a bug in Indy?

I need the "details" so I can compare timestamps & sizes too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a bug in `TIdFTP`.  It is more an omission in the Indy documentation.

`EIdReplyRFCError` means the FTP server itself is reporting an error in response to the command that `TIdFTP.List()` is sending.  Depending on the values of the `ADetails` parameter and `TIdFTP`'s `UseMLIS`+`CanUseMLS` properties, `List()` can send one of three different commands:

```
ADetails=False:

    NLST [ASpecifier]

ADetails=True:

  TIdFTP.UseMLIS=True and TIdFTP.CanUseMLS=True:

    MLSD [ASpecifier]

  TIdFTP.UseMLIS=False or TIdFTP.CanUseMLS=False:

    LIST [ASpecifier]
```

Thus:

```
FTP.List( aFiles, '', true ); // this works
// sends either 'LIST' or 'MLSD'

FTP.List( aFiles, '*.*', false ); // this works too
// sends 'NLST *.*'

FTP.List( aFiles, '*.*', true ); // this fails
// sends either 'LIST *.*' or 'MLSD *.*'

FTP.List( aFiles, '*.zip', true ); // this fails too
// sends either 'LIST *.zip' or 'MLSD *.zip'

FTP.List( '*.*', false ); // this works
// sends 'NLST *.*'

FTP.List( '*.*', true ); // this fails
// sends either 'LIST *.*' or 'MLSD *.*'
```

Note that all of the commands that "fail" have something in common - they might be sending an `MLSD ASpecifier` command.

Per [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), which defines the `LIST` and `NLST` commands:

> LIST (LIST)
>
> This command causes a list to be sent from the server to the
> passive DTP.  **If the pathname specifies a directory or other
> group of files, the server should transfer a list of files
> in the specified directory.  If the pathname specifies a
> file then the server should send current information on the
> file.  A null argument implies the user's current working or
> default directory.**  ...
>
> NAME LIST (NLST)
>
> This command causes a directory listing to be sent from
> server to user site.  **The pathname should specify a
> directory or other system-specific file group descriptor; a
> null argument implies the current directory.** ...

Per [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659), which defines the `MLSD` command:

> The MLST and MLSD commands each allow a single optional argument.
> **This argument may be either a directory name or, for MLST only, a
> file name.**  For these purposes, a "file name" is the name of any
> entity in the server NVFS which is not a directory.  Where TVFS is
> supported, any TVFS relative pathname valid in the current working
> directory, or any TVFS fully qualified pathname, may be given.  **If a
> directory name is given then MLSD must return a listing of the
> contents of the named directory, otherwise it issues a 501 reply, and
> does not open a data connection.**  ...
>
> **If no argument is given then MLSD must return a listing of the
> contents of the current working directory**, and MLST must return a
> listing giving information about the current working directory
> itself.  ...
>
> ...
>
> **If the Client-FTP sends an invalid argument, the server-FTP MUST
> reply with an error code of 501.**

`*.*` and `*.zip` are not directory names, thus the server will fail if `TIdFTP.List()` sends an `MLSD *.*` or `MLSD *.zip` command.  So it stands to reason that `TIdFTP.UseMLIS` and `TIdFTP.CanUseMLS` are likely both True in your case (`UseMLIS` is True by default, and `CanUseMLS` is commonly True on modern FTP servers).

The `MLSD` command does not support server-side filtering like the `LIST`/`NLST` commands do.  So you cannot use things like `*.*` and `*.zip` with `MLSD`.  You would have to retrieve the full directory listing and then ignore any entries that you are not interested in.  Otherwise, set `TIdFTP.UseMLIS` to False before calling `TIdFTP.List()`, but then you run the risk of `TIdFTP.DirectoryListing` incorrectly parsing the directory listing of some servers, as the format used by the `LIST` command was never standardized, and there are hundreds of custom formats being used all over the Internet (and why `TIdFTP` in Indy 10 includes dozens of listing parsers when `LIST` is used).  Unlike `MLSx`, which has a standardized format (which is why it was introduced in the first place, to replace the shortcomings of `LIST`).

Thus, what this all comes down to is - when `TIdFTP.UseMLIS` and `TIdFTP.CanUseMLS` are both True, `ASpecifier` **MUST** be blank or a directory, **NOT** a file mask.

The [`TIdFTP.List()` documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdFTP_List@TIdStrings@string@Boolean.html) *does* state that `List()` may internally call [`TIdFTP.ExtListDir()`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdFTP_ExtListDir@TIdStrings@string.html) to send an `MLSD` command, but it does not specifically mention this particular restriction on the `ASpecifier` parameter in that case:

> **If CanUseMLS contains True, the ExtListDir is called to capture and store the results of the FTP MLSD command in the ADest parameter variable instead of the LIST or NLST commands**. No additional processing is performed in the List method under this circumstance, and the method is exited.
>
> **When ADetails is False, only the file or directory name is returned in the ADest string list using the FTP NLST command**. When ADetails is True, List can return FTP server-dependent details including the file size, date modified, and file permissions for the Owner, Group, and User using the FTP LIST command.

The [`TIdFTP.ExtListDir()` documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdFTP_ExtListDir@TIdStrings@string.html) *does* state that its input parameter must be a directory name, though:

> The MLSD command, supported in ExtListDir, accepts an **optional directory name or relative path in Adirectory** for the directory listing. If am empty string is passed in ADirectory, the current directory is used for the directory listing operation.

On a side note: the `TIdFTP.DirFormat` property will tell you which listing format was detected after `TIdFTP.DirectoryListing` has parsed the results.  Or you can look at the `Details` and `UsedMLS` properties of `TListFTP.ListResult` (type-cast it to `TIdFTPListResult` to access the properties) to deduce which command was sent by `TIdFTP.List()` (if successful).

Comment: That's a great explanation Remy. Very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to include

`IdAllFTPListParsers`

In your `uses` clause and to disable `UseMLIS`.

Like so:

```
uses
  ....
  IdAllFTPListParsers;
   .....
procedure TForm1.DoThis;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if not IDFTP1.Connected then IDFTP1.Connect;
  IDFTP1.UseMLIS:= false;
  IDFTP1.List;
  for i:= 0 to IDFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count -1 do begin
    .. process directory items.
    IdFTP1.TransferType:= ftBinary;
    ..Get your files
```

Comment: This runs the risk of incorrect parsing, either on malformed/customized listings, or previously unknown listing formats (Indy has many listing parsers, but it doesn't parse *everything* that exists in the wild). `UseMLIS=True` is preferred when MLSx is available. That being said, what do you mean by "*if Indy does not see the `.` and `..` virtual directories it panics*"? `TIdFTP` does not care about those entries, they do not have to exist in the listing. So what exactly is it actually panicking about?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, after much experimentation this was the solution that worked for me. If you say the `./..` virtual directories don't matter I'll reinvestigate. I'm sure you're better informed than I am.